# CLLocationManager fails to update location on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cllocationmanager

On my non cellular iPad Mini I use CLLocationManager instance to get current location (once, not continually), so I start updating locations and finish when it updates or fails.

Getting location first time works fine, but later almost every try fails with LocationUnknown error. The situation is similar like in question
[iOS) GPS : didFailWithError is called after didUpdateLocations is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30426214/ios-gps-didfailwitherror-is-called-after-didupdatelocations-is-called).

So, what's the purpose?
I solved it by using new CLLocationManager instance every time, but it's kind a strange. On iPhone I can't reproduce this error.

Answer (score -1):

The wifi only model iPad does not have a GPS receiver.
 It is only capable of receiving location data through wifi data. 
You need a wifi + cellular iPad to accomplish location without wifi.

Note,
this also applies to iPod touch models. As a general rule for iOS devices, if it does not have a cell receiver, it must use wifi for GPS.

Comment: I know it hasn't, but getting location is still possible, and iPad gets location using only wi-fi successfully, but not every time - that is the problem described